# What is a luxury logo?

Tags: logo, trends

I have looked around for logo designs in the **luxury** category. I found that some luxury logo designs are complex but some are very simple.

Which trend is most used nowadays? Complex or Simple?

Comment: I don't know how this can be answered. Every person's perception of "luxury" os different. For the most part, opulence is probably the mood to go for.

Comment: Either complexly simple or simply complex ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A luxury logo is a logo that is attached to a luxury brand.

In that sense, there's nothing in particular style-wise that makes a logo luxurious. But lots of things could imply it:

- simplicity
- high attention paid to typography
- classic imagery
- 'luxurious' stylizing (think expensive implementation such as engraving, etching, gold plating, etc.)

Comment: `"A luxury logo is a logo that is attached to a luxury brand."` Yep, that pretty much covers it.

Comment: I agree, I don't think there's a single set graphical style that represents 'luxury'. It's all about context/branding a luxury car brand for example would be portrayed differently than a luxury restaurant which would be different than a luxury wedding invitation and  so on and so forth!